# Khovanov homology invarience under first reidemester move

Tags: homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am studying Khovanov homology from [five lectures on Khovanov homology](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606464.pdf)

and i want to try to show Khovanov homology is invariant under  first reidemester move but i can not understand how we can write

> $C^{î,*}(D)=C^{î,*}(D_0) \oplus C^{î-1,*}(D_{1})$.

where $D,D_0,D_1$ as in the picture below 
[image]

For example again in this paper it takes D as hopf link and i try to write it as a sum but i can not because if we take i=-2 then  $C^{-2,*}(D_0)=0 $ and $C^{-3,*}(D_{1})=0$ because they only have 1 negative cross , but if i take $C^{î,*}(D)=C^{î+1,*}(D_0) \oplus C^{î,*}(D_{1})$ it is true. Can you say where is my mistake ?

Comment: This is very late, but from what it sounds like you were trying to check this using the standard diagram from of the Hopf link. However this can't be done because the standard diagram for the Hopf link does not have any piece of it looking like the tangle $D$.